# C# WebBrowser Component

Tags: c#, html, css, webbrowser-control

Does anyone here know that what is the available webBrowser component that supports the latest HTML5/CSS3 feature? especially new syntax like webkit-gradient-radial or gradient-radial?

I have tried "Awesomemium", "Open Webkit Sharp", "Webkit.Net", but none of these fulfilled.

Comment: "What is the best" for any topic is not a good fit for SO as any answer is subjective.

Comment: I'm sorry for the "What is the best", its my first time here anyway. I have edited my question too. So in your experience, any webBrowser component in C#(.NET) that could archive that? Appreciate if you could help me =)

Comment: In what way did the ones you've tried not fit your needs?

Comment: Did you try [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) or [geckofx](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) embedded? They might be worth looking into.